# Why code not working correctly for printing having { in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a dictionary below:

```py
event = {
    "body-json": {},
    "params": {
        "path": {
            "matchphrase": "term"
        },
        "querystring": {
            "dataproduct.keyword": "health"
        },
        "header": {
            "Accept": "application/json"
        }
    },
    "resource-path": "/{matchphrase}"
}
```

I would like to access the above `event` dictionary keys & values and frame a new dictionary as follows:

`{"query": {"term" : {"dataproduct.keyword": "health"}}}`

Here is the code what I tried:

```py
a = event['params']['path']['matchphrase']  #term
b = list(event['params']['querystring'].keys())[0]   #dataproduct.keyword
c = list(event['params']['querystring'].values())[0]  #health
    
body=f"{query: {{a} : {{b}: {c}}}}"
print(body)
```

Am I missing something ?

Comment: `body = f'{{"query": {{{a}: {{{b}: {c}}}}}}}'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can create a dictionary and then get a string version of it using `json.dumps`.

```
import json
    
event = {
    "body-json": {},
    "params": {
        "path": {"matchphrase": "term"},
        "querystring": {"dataproduct.keyword": "health"},
        "header": {"Accept": "application/json"},
    },
    "resource-path": {"matchphrase}"},
}
    
a = event["params"]["path"]["matchphrase"]  # term
b = list(event["params"]["querystring"].keys())[0]  # dataproduct.keyword
c = list(event["params"]["querystring"].values())[0]  # health
    
result = {"query": {a: {b: c}}}
    
print(json.dumps(result))
```

**Output:**

```
{"query": {"term": {"dataproduct.keyword": "health"}}}
```

Comment: can you answer below question  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63050735/how-to-design-dynamodb-to-elastic-search-with-different-table

Comment: @aysh I've no experience with dynamodb and Elastic search.

Answer (score 2):

This should work :

```
body = {"query":{str(a):{str(b):str(c)}}}
print(body)
```

Answer (score 2):

The escaping is wrong.

Try this instead:

```
body = f'{{"query": {{{a!r}: {{{b!r}: {c!r}}}}}}}'
```

I've also added `!r` which will return the real representation (`repr`) of the object (so you don't need to artificially add quotes).