# How to design dynamodb to Elastic search with Insert/Modify/Remove

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, elasticsearch, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

How to pass this entire document into elastic search using Python? Is this this the right way to put into elastic search?

In dynamodb `id` is the primary key

How to insert in to dynamodb Below is the code

```
import boto3
from boto3.dynamodb.conditions import Key, And, Attr
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    dynamodb = boto3.resource ('dynamodb')
    table =dynamodb.Table('newtable')
    with table.batch_writer(overwrite_by_pkeys=['id']) as batch:
            batch.put_item(
                Item={
                    'id': '1',
                    'last_name': 'V',
                    'age': '2',
                }
            )
            batch.put_item(
                Item={
                    'id': '2',
                    'last_name': 'JJ',
                    'age': '7',
                }
            )
            batch.put_item(
                Item={
                    'id': '9',
                    'last_name': 'ADD',
                    'age': '95',
                }
            )
            batch.put_item(
                Item={
                    'id': '10',
                    'last_name': 'ADD',
                    'age': '95',
                }
            )
```

- How to push expected out into Elastic Search
- How to reflect automatically in ES if dynamodb content changes

I have gone through the link https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/indexing-amazon-dynamodb-content-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda/

Below is code I am getting error `ERROR: NameError("name 'event' is not defined")`

Code. * Before that trigger the below lambda function from the dynamodb table

```
import boto3
import json
import re
from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

session = boto3.session.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()
# s3 = session.resource('s3')
awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,
                   credentials.secret_key,
                   session.region_name, 'es',
                   session_token=credentials.token)
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['https://xx-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'],
    http_auth=awsauth,
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)
reserved_fields = ["uid", "_id", "_type", "_source", "_all", "_parent", "_fieldnames", "_routing", "_index", "_size",
                   "_timestamp", "_ttl"]


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    # Loop over the DynamoDB Stream records
    for record in event['Records']:

        try:

            if record['eventName'] == "INSERT":
                insert_document(es, record)
            elif record['eventName'] == "REMOVE":
                remove_document(es, record)
            elif record['eventName'] == "MODIFY":
                modify_document(es, record)

        except Exception as e:
            print("Failed to process:")
            print(json.dumps(record))
            print("ERROR: " + repr(e))
            continue


# Process MODIFY events
def modify_document(es, record):
    table = getTable(record)
    print("Dynamo Table: " + table)

    docId = docid(record)
    print("KEY")
    print(docId)

    # Unmarshal the DynamoDB JSON to a normal JSON
    doc = json.dumps(document())

    print("Updated document:")
    print(doc)

    # We reindex the whole document as ES accepts partial docs
    es.index(index=table,
             body=doc,
             id=docId,
             doc_type=table,
             refresh=True)

    print("Successly modified - Index: " + table + " - Document ID: " + docId)


def remove_document(es, record):
    table = getTable(record)
    print("Dynamo Table: " + table)

    docId = docid(record)
    print("Deleting document ID: " + docId)

    es.delete(index=table,
              id=docId,
              doc_type=table,
              refresh=True)

    print("Successly removed - Index: " + table + " - Document ID: " + docId)


# Process INSERT events
def insert_document(es, record):
    table = getTable(record)
    print("Dynamo Table: " + table)

    # Create index if missing
    if es.indices.exists(table) == False:
        print("Create missing index: " + table)

        es.indices.create(table,
                          body='{"settings": { "index.mapping.coerce": true } }')

        print("Index created: " + table)

    # Unmarshal the DynamoDB JSON to a normal JSON
    doc = json.dumps(document())

    print("New document to Index:")
    print(doc)

    newId = docid(record)
    es.index(index=table,
             body=doc,
             id=newId,
             doc_type=table,
             refresh=True)

    print("Successly inserted - Index: " + table + " - Document ID: " + newId)


def getTable(record):
    p = re.compile('arn:aws:dynamodb:.*?:.*?:table/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/.+')
    m = p.match(record['eventSourceARN'])
    if m is None:
        raise Exception("Table not found in SourceARN")
    return m.group(1).lower()


def document(event):
    result = []
    for r in event['Records']:
        tmp = {}
        for k, v in r['dynamodb']['NewImage'].items():
            if "S" in v.keys() or "BOOL" in v.keys():
                tmp[k] = v.get('S', v.get('BOOL', False))
            elif 'NULL' in v:
                tmp[k] = None
        result.append(tmp)
        for i in result:
            return i


def docid(event):
    result = []
    for r in event['Records']:
        tmp = {}
        for k, v in r['dynamodb']['Keys'].items():
            if "S" in v.keys() or "BOOL" in v.keys():
                tmp[k] = v.get('S', v.get('BOOL', False))
            elif 'NULL' in v:
                tmp[k] = None
        result.append(tmp)
    for newId in result:
        return newId
```

Getting error at document and docid

Individually both are giving output

```
result = []
for r in event['Records']:
    tmp = {}

    for k, v in r['dynamodb']['NewImage'].items():
    #for k, v in r['dynamodb']['Keys'].items():
        if "S" in v.keys() or "BOOL" in v.keys():
            tmp[k] = v.get('S', v.get('BOOL', False))
        elif 'NULL' in v:
            tmp[k] = None

    result.append(tmp)
for i in result:
    print (i)

event = {'Records': [{'eventID': '2339bc590c21035b84f8cc602b12c1d2', 'eventName': 'INSERT', 'eventVersion': '1.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1595908037.0, 'Keys': {'id': {'S': '9'}}, 'NewImage': {'last_name': {'S': 'Hus'}, 'id': {'S': '9'}, 'age': {'S': '95'}}, 'SequenceNumber': '3100000000035684810908', 'SizeBytes': 23, 'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'}, 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxx:table/glossary/stream/2020-07-28T00:26:55.462'}, {'eventID': 'xxxx', 'eventName': 'MODIFY', 'eventVersion': '1.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1595908037.0, 'Keys': {'id': {'S': '2'}}, 'NewImage': {'last_name': {'S': 'JJ'}, 'id': {'S': '2'}, 'age': {'S': '5'}}, 'SequenceNumber': '3200000000035684810954', 'SizeBytes': 21, 'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'}, 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxx:table/glossary/stream/2020-07-28T00:26:55.462'}, {'eventID': 'a9c90c0c4a5a4b64d0314c4557e94e28', 'eventName': 'INSERT', 'eventVersion': '1.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1595908037.0, 'Keys': {'id': {'S': '10'}}, 'NewImage': {'last_name': {'S': 'Hus'}, 'id': {'S': '10'}, 'age': {'S': '95'}}, 'SequenceNumber': '3300000000035684810956', 'SizeBytes': 25, 'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'}, 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxx:table/glossary/stream/2020-07-28T00:26:55.462'}, {'eventID': '288f4a424992e5917af0350b53f754dc', 'eventName': 'MODIFY', 'eventVersion': '1.1', 'eventSource': 'aws:dynamodb', 'awsRegion': 'us-east-1', 'dynamodb': {'ApproximateCreationDateTime': 1595908037.0, 'Keys': {'id': {'S': '1'}}, 'NewImage': {'last_name': {'S': 'V'}, 'id': {'S': '1'}, 'age': {'S': '2'}}, 'SequenceNumber': '3400000000035684810957', 'SizeBytes': 20, 'StreamViewType': 'NEW_IMAGE'}, 'eventSourceARN': 'arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:xxxx:table/glossary/stream/2020-07-28T00:26:55.462'}]}
```

Comment: Which line does `ERROR: NameError("name 'event' is not defined")` come from? Also what is the example of a record in dynamodb that you are trying to process?

Comment: @Marcin added piece of code to insert into dynamo

Comment: @SaiSreenivas event is parameter right in lambda handler, then how to call this locally to another variable

Comment: @SaiSreenivas, already tried

Comment: @SaiSreenivas document(event), docId(event)

Comment: @SaiSreenivas document and docid

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the following. I tried to **replicate** the issue and can **confirm** the error of

```
ERROR: NameError("name 'event' is not defined")
```

I used **simulated** INSERT `event` from DynamoDb stream, based on your example and **my own table**:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventID": "b8b993cf16d1aacb61b40411b39e0b1f",
      "eventName": "INSERT",
      "eventVersion": "1.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "dynamodb": {
        "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1595922821.0,
        "Keys": {
          "id": {
            "N": "1"
          }
        },
        "NewImage": {
          "last_name": {
            "S": "V"
          },
          "id": {
            "N": "1"
          },
          "age": {
            "S": "2"
          }
        },
        "SequenceNumber": "25200000000020406897812",
        "SizeBytes": 22,
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      },
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:11111:table/newtable/stream/2020-07-28T06:59:38.569"
    },
    {
      "eventID": "e5d5bec988945c06ffc879cf16b89bf7",
      "eventName": "INSERT",
      "eventVersion": "1.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "dynamodb": {
        "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1595922821.0,
        "Keys": {
          "id": {
            "N": "9"
          }
        },
        "NewImage": {
          "last_name": {
            "S": "ADD"
          },
          "id": {
            "N": "9"
          },
          "age": {
            "S": "95"
          }
        },
        "SequenceNumber": "25300000000020406897813",
        "SizeBytes": 25,
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      },
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:11111:table/newtable/stream/2020-07-28T06:59:38.569"
    },
    {
      "eventID": "f1a7c9736253b5ef28ced38ed5ff645b",
      "eventName": "INSERT",
      "eventVersion": "1.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "dynamodb": {
        "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1595922821.0,
        "Keys": {
          "id": {
            "N": "2"
          }
        },
        "NewImage": {
          "last_name": {
            "S": "JJ"
          },
          "id": {
            "N": "2"
          },
          "age": {
            "S": "7"
          }
        },
        "SequenceNumber": "25400000000020406897819",
        "SizeBytes": 23,
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      },
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:11111:table/newtable/stream/2020-07-28T06:59:38.569"
    },
    {
      "eventID": "bfcbad9dc19883e4172e6dc25e66637b",
      "eventName": "INSERT",
      "eventVersion": "1.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "dynamodb": {
        "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1595922821.0,
        "Keys": {
          "id": {
            "N": "10"
          }
        },
        "NewImage": {
          "last_name": {
            "S": "ADD"
          },
          "id": {
            "N": "10"
          },
          "age": {
            "S": "95"
          }
        },
        "SequenceNumber": "25500000000020406897820",
        "SizeBytes": 25,
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      },
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:11111:table/newtable/stream/2020-07-28T06:59:38.569"
    }
  ]
}
```

Example MODIFY `event`:

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventID": "4e4629c88aa00e366c89a293d9c82d54",
      "eventName": "MODIFY",
      "eventVersion": "1.1",
      "eventSource": "aws:dynamodb",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "dynamodb": {
        "ApproximateCreationDateTime": 1595924589.0,
        "Keys": {
          "id": {
            "N": "2"
          }
        },
        "NewImage": {
          "last_name": {
            "S": "zhgdhfgdh"
          },
          "id": {
            "N": "2"
          },
          "age": {
            "S": "7"
          }
        },
        "OldImage": {
          "last_name": {
            "S": "JJ"
          },
          "id": {
            "N": "2"
          },
          "age": {
            "S": "7"
          }
        },
        "SequenceNumber": "25600000000020408264140",
        "SizeBytes": 49,
        "StreamViewType": "NEW_AND_OLD_IMAGES"
      },
      "eventSourceARN": "arn:aws:dynamodb:us-east-1:34234:table/newtable/stream/2020-07-28T06:59:38.569"
    }
  ]
}
```

Modified code of lambda function, which I can **confirm does not produce errors** now:

```
import boto3
import json
import re

from requests_aws4auth import AWS4Auth
from elasticsearch import Elasticsearch, RequestsHttpConnection

session = boto3.session.Session()
credentials = session.get_credentials()

s3 = session.resource('s3')

awsauth = AWS4Auth(credentials.access_key,
                  credentials.secret_key,
                  session.region_name, 'es',
                  session_token=credentials.token)

    
es = Elasticsearch(
    ['https://vpc-test-dmamain-452frn764ggb4a.us-east-1.es.amazonaws.com'],
    use_ssl=True,
    verify_certs=True,
    http_auth=awsauth,
    connection_class=RequestsHttpConnection
)
reserved_fields = ["uid", "_id", "_type", "_source", "_all", "_parent", "_fieldnames", "_routing", "_index", "_size",
                   "_timestamp", "_ttl"]


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    #dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb')

    # Loop over the DynamoDB Stream records
    for record in event['Records']:
            
        if record['eventName'] == "INSERT":
            insert_document(event, es, record)
        elif record['eventName'] == "REMOVE":
            remove_document(event, es, record)
        elif record['eventName'] == "MODIFY":
            modify_document(event, es, record)


# Process MODIFY events
def modify_document(event, es, record):
    table = getTable(record)
    print("Dynamo Table: " + table)

    docId = docid(event, event)
    print("KEY")
    print(docId)

    # Unmarshal the DynamoDB JSON to a normal JSON
    doc = json.dumps(document(event))

    print("Updated document:")
    print(doc)

    # We reindex the whole document as ES accepts partial docs
    es.index(index=table,
             body=doc,
             id=docId,
             doc_type=table,
             refresh=True)

    print("Successly modified - Index: " , table , " - Document ID: " , docId)


def remove_document(event, es, record):
    
    table = getTable(record)
    
    print("Dynamo Table: " + table)

    docId = docid(event, event)
    print("Deleting document ID: ", docId)

    es.delete(index=table,
              id=docId,
              doc_type=table,
              refresh=True)

    print("Successly removed - Index: ", table, " - Document ID: " , docId)


# Process INSERT events
def insert_document(event, es, record):
    table = getTable(record)
    print("Dynamo Table: " + table)

    # Create index if missing
    if es.indices.exists(table) == False:
        print("Create missing index: " + table)

        es.indices.create(table,
                          body='{"settings": { "index.mapping.coerce": true } }')

        print("Index created: " + table)

    # Unmarshal the DynamoDB JSON to a normal JSON
    doc = json.dumps(document(event))

    print("New document to Index:")
    print(doc)

    newId = docid(event, record)
    
    es.index(index=table,
             body=doc,
             id=newId,
             doc_type=table,
             refresh=True)

    print("Successly inserted - Index: " , table + " - Document ID: " , newId)


def getTable(record):
    p = re.compile('arn:aws:dynamodb:.*?:.*?:table/([0-9a-zA-Z_-]+)/.+')
    m = p.match(record['eventSourceARN'])
    if m is None:
        raise Exception("Table not found in SourceARN")
    return m.group(1).lower()


def document(event):
    result = []
    for r in event['Records']:
        tmp = {}
        for k, v in r['dynamodb']['NewImage'].items():
            if "S" in v.keys() or "BOOL" in v.keys():
                tmp[k] = v.get('S', v.get('BOOL', False))
            elif 'NULL' in v:
                tmp[k] = None
        result.append(tmp)
        for i in result:
            return i


def docid(event, record):
    result = []
    for r in event['Records']:
        tmp = {}
        for k, v in r['dynamodb']['Keys'].items():
            if "S" in v.keys() or "BOOL" in v.keys():
                tmp[k] = v.get('S', v.get('BOOL', False))
            elif 'NULL' in v:
                tmp[k] = None
        result.append(tmp)
    for newId in result:
        return newId
```

I **haven't verified** if data is correctly written, modified or inserted into ElasticSearch. But I had ES domain running and used in the lambda to verify if lambda can connect to it and run the queries.

Example output from lambda for INSERT event:

```
Dynamo Table: newtable
New document to Index:
{"last_name": "V", "age": "2"}
Successly inserted - Index:  newtable - Document ID:  {}
Dynamo Table: newtable
New document to Index:
{"last_name": "V", "age": "2"}
Successly inserted - Index:  newtable - Document ID:  {}
Dynamo Table: newtable
New document to Index:
{"last_name": "V", "age": "2"}
Successly inserted - Index:  newtable - Document ID:  {}
Dynamo Table: newtable
New document to Index:
{"last_name": "V", "age": "2"}
Successly inserted - Index:  newtable - Document ID:  {}

Example output from lambda from MODIFY event:
```

Updated document:

```
{
    "last_name": "zhgdhfgdh",
    "age": "7"
}
Successly modified - Index:  newtable  - Document ID:  
{}
```

I think `docid` requires further investigation if it works correctly as it seems to return empty dict:

```
 Document ID:  {}
```

Comment: @SaiSreenivas Its was necessary. You have to pass the event from the handler to all other places where it is used.

Comment: I got error G, [Line number 42 ERROR] TypeError: document() missing 1 required positional argument: 'event'  `modify_document(event, es, record)`

Comment: @aysh I haven't verify modify, I don't have event for that yet.

Comment: @aysh It would be helpful if you could provide all these events, like I did for INSERT. Otherwise I have to re-create everything, which can be difficult to do from scratch.

Comment: I have added small event in the code which place do need to change in the code?

Comment: `doc = json.dumps(document(event))` was missing in the `modify_document`. I added it now.

Comment: @aysh MODIFY example event added. and lambda also works.

Answer (score 2):

Most people use DynamoDB Streams with Lambda which pushes it into ElasticSearch.

[Here is a blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/indexing-amazon-dynamodb-content-with-amazon-elasticsearch-service-using-aws-lambda/) about it. it is a little old, so you might need to play with things a bit.